# Book of support for reading the Fulton book.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, reference-works

I would like to know about some support reference that could help me in reading the Fulton (Algebraic Curves). Sometimes, some definitions I find in Fulton's book are not clear to me. So maybe with another book to look up on some specific topics I could move forward faster in Fulton's chapters if I could rely on another reference on specific topics, definitions, and theorems.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have specific examples ? Fulton's book should be readable with no background in algebraic geometry (it was my first book in AG) and minimal background in commutative algebra (Atiyah-Macdonald is certainly enough).

Comment: Yes I can give examples ... when I was reading about Coordinates Rings, Discrete Valuation Rings ... I had doubts about some found statements. Then I managed to solve them consulted an extra material.

Comment: Did you try Atiyah-Macdonald, Introduction to Commutative algebra ?

Comment: No. But I'm now in Chapter 5 (Fulton), Projective plane curves. Atiyah-Macdonald, Introduction to Commutative Algebra, can you help me at this point?

Comment: What kind of help are you waiting for ? You can read the relevant chapters in the book by Atiyah-Macdonald, and it should be enough to be able to follow the book by Fulton.

Comment: Speaking to someone who can find and identify with this question. Here's a good help: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/  Just click on the link: AG